# What is the difference between invertible sheaf and sheaf of ring on a ringed space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, ringed-spaces

According to Hartshorne, an invertible sheaf $\mathcal{L}$ on a ringed space $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ is a **locally** free sheaf of rank 1. So, this means that there exists a cover $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ of X such that $\mathcal{L}_{{U}_i}$ is $\mathcal{O}_X(U_i)$. My question is that why is $\mathcal{L}$ not a **globally** free sheaf of rank 1? In other words, by the gluing property of sheaves $\mathcal{L}_{V}$ should be $\mathcal{O}_X(V)$ for an open set $V$ in $X$. Am I right?

Comment: No, you're not correct. Have you seen the examples of $\mathcal{O}(n)$ on $\Bbb P^r_k$? This will give you many examples to see what's going on. For instance, the global sections are polynomials of degree $n$ in $x_0,\cdots,x_r$, which is almost always not the same as $k$, the global sections of $\mathcal{O}$.

Comment: You're being imprecise when you say "$\mathcal{L}_{{U}_i}$ is $\mathcal{O}_X(U_i)$."  For one thing, $\mathcal{L}_{{U}_i}$ is a sheaf while $\mathcal{O}_X(U_i)$ is a ring. The actual definition is that there is an isomorphism $\varphi_i: \mathcal{L}|_{{U}_i} \to \mathcal{O}_X|_{U_i}$ for each $i$. In order for these $\varphi_i$ to glue to give a global isomorphism $\varphi: \mathcal{L} \to \mathcal{O}_X$, you'd need $\varphi_i$ and $\varphi_j$ to agree on the overlap $U_i \cap U_j$. But there is no reason for this to hold in general, and often there will be some cohomological obstruction.

Comment: I would also suggest digesting how one can understand the Moebius band as a line bundle over its core circle as you are coming to grips with this concept. Just as with a manifold, the entire point of a locally free sheaf is that it is glued from pieces that are locally indistinguishable to obtain an object that is globally nontrivial.

Comment: @HankScorpio Thanks, will look it up.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense to say that there is an isomorphism rather than saying they are equal. And the analogy with manifolds was helpful as well. Thank you!

Comment: Just to be sure, these $\varphi_i's$ are module isomorphisms, right?

Comment: They are isomorphisms of $\mathcal{O}_X|_{U_i}$-modules.